# How to restore Debian server's /var/lib datas

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, sudo

I made a big mistake : While administrating and making settings, I accidentally deleted /var/lib folder. The result is that I can no longer use any dpkg commands, so I"ve lost my mysql database. I of course have backups, but cannot re-install MySql. Th whole /var/lib folder has been trashed. Sudo command doesn't work anymore as well.

Is there a way to fix that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop digging. Turn off the machine, mount the drive read only, use a live CD, or `dd if=/DRIVETORECOVER of=/spareDrive`
2. Foremost, or ext3undelete